# what are different ways to Sync data between multiple nodes for in-memory cache

Tags: caching

I was reading how can we sync data between multiple nodes for in-memory cache.

I understand we can use centralised/distributed cache like Redis or Hazelcast, but given the limitation of an existing application(data-intensive, build on SpringBoot, java, MS SQL, high mobile usage) if someone want to implement his own data sync technique what are different ways.

I did some research but couldn't find anything concrete,I can find data sync between cache and database but nothing much on between mutiple nodes for in-memory cache.

I find one article which explain data synchronisation issue : [In-memory cache VS. centralized cache in a distributed system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056786/in-memory-cache-vs-centralized-cache-in-a-distributed-system)

I also tried finding the internal implementation of Redis and Hazelcast cache how they keep data in sync across nodes, but they are abstracting the user from their algorithms.

I can think of following ways to do it:

1. kafka pub-sub approach
2. Rest API
3. UDP multicast :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast

I would like to know if these approaches will work, when we have following restrictions:

- we cannot afford high data sync lag
- data loss  delivery
- out of order